# Check which element was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have some images and when they are clicked, it will pop up with an alert like so:

```js
$('.image').click( function() { alert( 'Clicked it!' ); } );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="imageHolder" style="width: 80%; display:  inline;">
 <div class="image">
  <img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/nO2hl.png">
 </div>
 <div class="image">
  <img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/IkjJW.png">
 </div>
 <div class="image">
  <img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/QrKSV.png">
 </div>
</div>
```

How can I modify this so that if the first image was clicked it would alert with "1 was clicked" and if the second image was clicked it would alert with "2 was clicled" and so on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the JQuery [.index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/) method and concatenate the index of the clicked `div` to the string in your `alert`.

Since the first index of an array in JS is `0`, you will also have to add `1` to the returned index if you want to start at `1`. Try the snippet below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.image').click(function() {
    alert($(this).index() + 1 + ' was clicked!');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="imageHolder" style="width: 80%; display: inline;">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/nO2hl.png">
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/IkjJW.png">
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/QrKSV.png">
  </div>
</div>
```